# How can I do this search with flutter?

Tags: api, flutter, dart

I need to enter two text boxes where by pressing on them I give you the option to enter addresses from google maps. And then when pressing search with those two addresses, throw me the results of trips that match.

I am developing a kind of travel booking.

Answer (score 0):

This is third party feature. An efficient way to achieve is by using the Google Maps Api
[Google Maps Api - Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete)
Flutter package [Flutter Google Places](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_google_places)